# Problem reading FullHttpRequest request content with Proxy

Tags: http, proxy, netty, little-proxy

I'm trying to develop code that can filter requests, modify them, etc. The Proxy intercepts requests correctly and is able to display the correct Uri for example. However, I cannot read the contents of the http package. In fact, the request.content (). ReadableBytes () function returns 0.

below the code:

```
HttpProxyServer server =
        DefaultHttpProxyServer.bootstrap()
                .withAddress(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 8080))
                .withTransparent(true)
                .withFiltersSource(new HttpFiltersSourceAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public int getMaximumRequestBufferSizeInBytes() {
                        return 512 * 1024;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public int getMaximumResponseBufferSizeInBytes() {
                        return 50 * 1024 * 1024;
                    }
                    public HttpFilters filterRequest(HttpRequest originalRequest, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
                        return new HttpFiltersAdapter(originalRequest) {
                            @Override
                            public HttpResponse clientToProxyRequest(HttpObject httpObject) {
                                FullHttpRequest request = (FullHttpRequest) httpObject;
                                CompositeByteBuf contentBuf = (CompositeByteBuf) request.content();
                                System.out.println(request.getUri());
                                System.out.println(request.content().readableBytes());
```

So the question is: why i can't read the body of the request?

Comment: Please clarify if you are using netty directly or through a higher level framework

Comment: Also this seems like a cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68150057/problem-reading-fullhttprequest-request-content-with-proxy